# How to call Stored Procedures (with 2 parameters) in a Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, sqlparameter

I have stored procedures with same parameters (server name and date). I want to write a stored procedure and Exec them in that SP (called it SP_All).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_All]
AS
BEGIN
exec sp_1   @myDate datetime, @ServerName sysname
exec sp_2   @myDate datetime, @ServerName sysname
exec sp_3   @myDate datetime, @ServerName sysname
exec sp_4   @myDate datetime, @ServerName sysname
END
Go
```

error: Must declare the scalar variable "@myDate".

Comment: put parameters /@myDate datetime, /@ServerName sysname

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Although your question is a basic one, +1 for adding a complete code example, the complete error message and an explanation of what the code should do. Too many questions lack at least one of these...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see two issues here:

1. Your procedure apparently takes two parameters, `@myDate` and `@ServerName`, which you have not declared yet. Do so by adding the names and the types between the procedure name and AS.
2. When calling sp_1 to sp_4, there is no need to specify the data type of the parameters again (that's been taken care of by the declaration, see point 1).

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_All]
       @myDate datetime,
       @ServerName sysname
   AS
   BEGIN
       exec sp_1 @myDate, @ServerName
       exec sp_2 @myDate, @ServerName
       exec sp_3 @myDate, @ServerName
       exec sp_4 @myDate, @ServerName
   END
   ```

Comment: Dear Heinzi, marc_s  and Devart thanks for comments. It works now! I know it is a basic question. Hope I will be an expert like all of you. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_All]

       @myDate DATETIME
     , @ServerName SYSNAME

AS BEGIN

     EXEC dbo.sp_1 @myDate, @ServerName
     EXEC dbo.sp_2 @myDate, @ServerName
     EXEC dbo.sp_3 @myDate, @ServerName
     EXEC dbo.sp_4 @myDate, @ServerName

END
```

Answer (score 2):

You are executing stored procedures the wrong way

```
exec sp_1 @myDate datetime, @ServerName sysname
```

is completely wrong syntax.

When you have to execute a stored procedure with parameters, first declare parameter and pass it..

```
declare @myDate datetime
declare @ServerName sysname

exec sp_1 @myDate, @ServerName
```

This is the right approach..

Comment: Here is a misunderstanding. I have declared all parameters in other SP and now I just needed to execute them. Heinzi nd Devart answers' are correct and working.